# Select2 can not select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I am using select2 4.0.6 in my java project. use JSON API for source data. Its shown dropdown items but can not select single item by typing. But selecting by mouse its works fine.

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/taumal/mrk7615g/) link

And my sample code as follows-

```js
            
            function loadMedicines(manufacturerId) {
                $("[id $= '.medicine']").select2({
                    ajax: {
                        url: url+'?id='+manufacturerId,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        processResults: function (jsonData) {
                            return {
                                results: $.map(jsonData.data, function (item) {
                                    return {
                                        id: item.id,
                                        text: item.brandName
                                    }
                                })
                            };
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

```html
          <label>Manufacturer</label>

          <select id="manufacturer" name="manufacturer" onchange="loadMedicines(this.value);">
            <option value="0">Please Select</option>
            <option value="2">ACI</option>
            <option value="1">Beximco</option>
            <option value="3">Square</option>
          </select>


    <label>Medicines</label>

          <select id="lists0.medicine" name="lists[0].medicine" class="reqDetMed">
            <option value="">Please Select</option>
          </select>

          <select id="lists1.medicine" name="lists[1].medicine" class="reqDetMed">
            <option value="">Please Select</option>
          </select>
```

Comment: is your select2 in a modal? could be a `tabIndex` issue

Comment: no its not in modal. just in a form. you can check jsfiddle link. there I tried to explain...